# How to convert 1 to true or 0 to false upon model fetch

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a model that is set with a JSON response from a mysql database. The model data is set with true or false into a boolean/tinyint field in the database, which uses `1` or `0`.

In my view, I have a binding that checks for a boolean with underscore's `_.isBoolean`. Of course, when my model receives the data, it is set with `1` or `0` instead of true or false and the `_.isBoolean` check fails.

Is there anyway to either correctly have my JSON response from mysql be a boolean true or false value instead of `1` or `0`, or preferably, is there a way to have my model update itself upon fetch (and before the view renders) to cast `true` or `false` based on it's 1 or 0 property?

e.g. my model's data looks like `{"isChecked":"1"}` when I need it to be `{"isChecked":true}`

Thank you greatly for any suggestions you may have!

Comment: what is the server side technology used?

Comment: PHP, the response is being written out with a json_encode on the query result

Comment: did you try with the way: isChecked=isChecked?true : false

Answer (score 238, accepted):

All you need is convert `string` to `int` with `+` and convert the result to boolean with `!!`:

```
var response = {"isChecked":"1"};
response.isChecked = !!+response.isChecked
```

You can do this manipulation in the `parse` method:

```
parse: function (response) {
  response.isChecked = !!+response.isChecked;
  return response;
}
```

**UPDATE**: 7 years later, I find `Number(string)` conversion more elegant. Also mutating an object is not the best idea. That being said:

```
parse: function (response) {
  return Object.assign({}, response, {
    isChecked: !!Number(response.isChecked), // OR
    isChecked: Boolean(Number(response.isChecked))
  });
}
```

Comment: +1 For converting into `int` first.

    `!!+"1"; // true`, 
    `!!+"0"; // false`,
    `!!+1; // true`,
    `!!+0; // false`

Answer (score 102):

Use a double not:

```
!!1 = true;

!!0 = false;

obj.isChecked = !!parseInt(obj.isChecked);
```

Comment: This worked for me but for some reason I had an I still had to parse it out `value = (!!parseInt(value) ? true : false)`

Comment: Just to be sure, `!!2` or any other number `= false`, right?

Comment: No, !!2 would be true, it'll only be false for 0

Answer (score 97):

Here's another option that's longer but may be more readable:

```
Boolean(Number("0")); // false
Boolean(Number("1")); // true
```

Answer (score 20):

## Assigning Comparison to property value

### JavaScript

You could assign the comparison of the property to `"1"`

```
obj["isChecked"] = (obj["isChecked"]==="1");
```

This only evaluates for a String value of `"1"` though. Other variables evaulate to false like an actual `typeof number` would be false. (i.e. `obj["isChecked"]=1`)

If you wanted to be indiscrimate about `"1"` or `1`, you could use:

```
obj["isChecked"] = (obj["isChecked"]=="1");
```

#### Example Outputs

```
console.log(obj["isChecked"]==="1"); // true
console.log(obj["isChecked"]===1); // false
console.log(obj["isChecked"]==1); // true
console.log(obj["isChecked"]==="0"); // false
console.log(obj["isChecked"]==="Elephant"); // false
```

### PHP

Same concept in PHP

```
$obj["isChecked"] = ($obj["isChecked"] == "1");
```

The same operator limitations as stated above for JavaScript apply.

## Double Not

The 'double not' also works. It's confusing when people first read it but it works in both languages for integer/number type values. It however does not work in JavaScript for string type values as they always evaluate to true:

### JavaScript

```
!!"1"; //true
!!"0"; //true
!!1; //true
!!0; //false
!!parseInt("0",10); // false
```

### PHP

```
echo !!"1"; //true
echo !!"0"; //false
echo !!1; //true
echo !!0; //false
```

Comment: good idea Christopher, i was able to achieve this by writing: ` this.model.set('isChecked', (this.model.get('isChecked') === '1'))` in  the initialize function of my backbone view.

Answer (score 2):

```
Boolean(Number(myVar))
```

or

```
!!+myVar
```

Comment: This is duplicating previous answers. IMO it should be deleted to minimize the clutter.

Answer (score 0):

Another work around is to simply create an array holding the booleans and assigning the corresponding boolean to it's index. Let me explain below:

```
const bools = [false,true];
```

Access the boolean you want with either int or str.

`bools['0'] (str)` or `bools[0] (int)` should work just fine in the browser and yield the correct value. I recently used this for setting a checkbox value.

Hope this helped