# How to check boolean field of mysql table and convertion of 0 or 1 value to true/false in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

In my query i have 3 tinyint fields which by fetching gives 0/1 value. But after fetching all the data i want to encode that result into JSON format which should get true/false instead of 0/1.
In my code i have done type conversion, which gives proper result. But i should write for all the tinyint fields which i dont want.
Is there any method to check tinyint field and for conversion.

```
PHP CODE: 


$result= mysql_query("select incident_main.inc_id as incident_id,
                      ward_master.ward_id as 'ward_id', 
                      GROUP_CONCAT(incident_log.inclog_date) as revisit_dates ,
                      inc_GISlat as lat,
                      inc_GISlon as lon,
            inc_closed as  b_is_closed,
              inc_closeDate as closed_date,
                      incident_statuscd.inc_status_desc as status, 
                      inc_date as 'incident_date', 
                      inc_patientName as 'patient_name',
                      inc_patientAge as 'patient_age',
                      inc_patientGender as 'patient_gender',
                      inc_patientMobile as'patient_mobile' ,
                      inc_patientAddress as 'patient_address',
                      inc_type as type,
                      inc_typeOther as 'type_other',
                      inc_diagnosis as diagnosis,
                      inc_recurrence as recurrence,
              inc_hospitalized as b_hospitalized, 
                      inc_treatment as treatment ,
                      inc_treatmentOther as 'treatment_other' 
                  from 
                      incident_main,
                      incident_statuscd ,
                      ward_master,
                      incident_log 
                  where 
                      inc_status=incident_statuscd.inc_status_id 
                     and 
                      incident_main.inc_patientWard=ward_master.ward_id 
                     and incident_log.inc_id=incident_main.inc_id ") 
                      or die(mysql_error);
while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 foreach($res as $key => $value) {
     if(substr( $key, 0, 2 ) === "b_") {
         // assign new value
         $res[substr($key,2,strlen($key))] = !!$value;
         //clean up old value
         unset($res[$key]);
         };

  }
  $data=array_filter($res);

echo json_encode($data, true);
```

Please help!! 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: JS also have type convertion. So do not do it, if you don't want to.

Comment: can you please explain more specifically ....where and how?

Comment: [refer this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313222/how-to-convert-1-to-true-or-0-to-false-upon-model-fetch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real way to check for tinyint in PHP

what you could do is prepend your variables with a b_ and use regex/strpos/substr to filter that to typecast that into boolean. That way you only have to adapt your query and the script will do the casting for you.

```
$result= mysql_query("select incident_main.inc_id as incident_id,
                      ward_master.ward_id as 'ward_id', 
                      GROUP_CONCAT(incident_log.inclog_date) as revisit_dates ,
                      inc_GISlat as lat,
                      inc_GISlon as lon,
    --->              inc_closed as  b_is_closed,
    --->              inc_reviewed as b_is_reviewed,
                      inc_closeDate as closed_date,
                      incident_statuscd.inc_status_desc as status, 
                      inc_date as 'incident_date', 
                      inc_patientName as 'patient_name',
                      inc_patientAge as 'patient_age',
                      inc_patientGender as 'patient_gender',
                      inc_patientMobile as'patient_mobile' ,
                      inc_patientAddress as 'patient_address',
                      inc_type as type,
                      inc_typeOther as 'type_other',
                      inc_diagnosis as diagnosis,
                      inc_recurrence as recurrence,
    --->              inc_hospitalized as b_hospitalized, 
                      inc_treatment as treatment ,
                      inc_treatmentOther as 'treatment_other' 
                  from 
                      incident_main,
                      incident_statuscd ,
                      ward_master,
                      incident_log 
                  where 
                      inc_status=incident_statuscd.inc_status_id 
                     and 
                      incident_main.inc_patientWard=ward_master.ward_id 
                     and incident_log.inc_id=incident_main.inc_id ") 
                      or die(mysql_error);
while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 foreach($res as $key => $value) {
     if(substr( $key, 0, 2 ) === "b_") {
         // assign new value
         $res[substr($key,2,strlen($key))] = !!$value;
         //clean up old value
         unset($res[$key]);
     }
  }
  $data=array_filter($res,'not_null');
}


function not_null($test) {
   return !($test === null);
}
```

**EDIT**

added a way to revert the boolean marked key to original value for normal code execution.
Yes its a duplicate, but might help for further implementation/code execution without renaming everything to b_

Comment: should i pass all boolean variables in the place of b_  ?

Comment: When you design the query where you give all the fields the names you want like you are doing here, just add a b_ in front of all the fields that should be a boolean according to you.
That way you dont have to worry about it in php code if you use my tidbit of code.

Comment: Just make sure my code is run right after while statement. Also, if you really prefer the original names you gave it for the rest of your code you can also add the edit I am now making

Comment: this method is working good,but all boolean variable are coming at the end of   result I want result to be displayed as specified in the  query .Can you please check and help.

Comment: And, order of variables doenst matter. The keys attached to them does matter. You will access them both in the end by the keys they have in the array. So the order of the array, especially when using an associative array is not important.

Comment: Also, the overhead caused by cloning an array to resolve that issue would not be worth it because its only for your esthetic purposes, but the php engine couldnt care less in which order the variables are supplied, or should the json code nor should any other code.

Comment: so, how to resolve this?..Because i need json result same as i supplied in the query

Comment: Do you even know how variables work? The json encoded still get the same values. Only in a differnt order. but order is **not important** it is not an indexed array you know. its an **associative array** All the keys are still in the same order. If the order is important to you you are not decoding the json properly on the other end.

Comment: yes sir I agree to you, The actual problem is when i tend to use array filter statement whole of my output is getting affected. If i dont use array_filter I get the result but with null values, also the result of array is deviating from the order.

Comment: Edit your question and post the array filter... you are doing something really weird there. i'd like to see how your "modified" code looks

Comment: So you only want the boolean values right? `array_filter($res,'is_bool');`
That way if the is_bool returns true it will only leave you with the boolean values.

Comment: I want all the values int, varchar, boolean other than NULL values..so i want to remove only null values.

Comment: Ah, okay. look at my 2nd edit. added a not_null function. Please for your reference read http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: Thank you so much. array_filter is working awesome with not_null function :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to distinguish `TINYINT` and `integer` in *PHP*. Therefore you’ll need to list the fields you want to transform. The shorten version of this is shown below:

```
$a = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 100, 'c' => 0 ];
$bools = ['a', 'c'];   // list of fields to transform

$result = array_map(function($item) use($bools,&$a) { 
  $key=key($a); next($a);  // we need a key to check it’s name
  return in_array($key, $bools) ? (bool)$item : $item; 
}, $a);

print_r(json_encode($result, true));
//⇒ {"a":true,"b":100,"c":false}
```

The latter will cast `integer` to `bool` if and only the `key` is listed in `$bools` array. For further details please refer to [`array_map` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

Hope it helps.

Comment: It’s a callback parameter; for every call to `function` during walking through the array it contains an array element.

Comment: while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
  $bools = ['inc_hospitalized'];
  
  $user[]= array_filter(($row));
  $result1 = array_map(function($item) use($bools,&$user) { 
  $key=key($user); next($user);  // we need a key to check it’s name
  return in_array($key, $bools) ? (bool)$item : $item; 
}, $user);

        } this is how i implemented your code but it is not working.

Comment: In my code $a is coming from database as array ,so what to do for this?

Comment: It does not matter, where your array is coming from. I can’t get the meaning of `$user[]= array_filter(($row)); ` BTW, `array_filter` returns an array already, but it requires a second argument. I bet you have php errors/warning in this line. And **you don’t need to deal with rows, deal with the whole `$result` array**.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing another function:

```
private function isTrue($input){
     if ((bool)$input){
          return "true";
     }else{
          return "false";
     }         
}
```

Which when called with the 0 or 1 returns text "true" or "false". Then add the call for each tinyint to be encoded:

```
...
$row['hospitalized'] = isTrue($row['hospitalized']);
...
```

Comment: By using your code it's possible but i should specify for all boolean fields , any other method is there to avoid this call to the function again and again?

Answer (score -2):

JS code:

```
if(1) 
    alert('true');
if(0)
    alert('false');
```

Comment: I have some integer fields.. So what about that.?

Comment: Why do you keep going on about JS? This question about PHP.