# Convert php function return values to true/false

Tags: php

I first referred to this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313222/how-to-convert-1-to-true-or-0-to-false-upon-model-fetch), but it did not solve my problem.

I am having something like:

```
  $message .=   "\n\tWhether $testOutputDir is a directory:" . (!!is_dir($testOutputDir))
                . "\n\tWhether $outputDir is a directory:" . is_dir($outputDir)
                . "\n\tWhether $outputDir is readabale:" . is_readable($outputDir)
                ....
```

I just want to print something as follows:

```
       Whether /a is a directory: true
       Whether /b is a directory: true
```

But it prints as follows:

```
       Whether /a is a directory: 1
       Whether /b is a directory: 1
```

Any suggestions to solve this?

**EDIT:**

I could check `func == 1 ? TRUE : FALSE`. But I am expecting a simple cast or similar.

Comment: even if you do `echo true`, it will still print `1`. so need a `bool2str` function

Comment: @Fabricator So I should use ternary operator. Is it the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, when a boolean value is converted to a string, you get `'1'` (for `true`) and `''` (empty string, for `false`). If you want otherwise, you're going to have to explicitly convert the boolean value to a string.

There is no cast that will get you the result you want. One way to solve your problem would be to pass your value into this function:

```
function stringForBool($bool) {
    return ($bool ? 'true' : 'false');
}

//use like:
echo stringForBool(isReadable($outputDir));
```

You could also inline this function directly in your code, rather than calling it, but if you're using it more than a few times, that would become awfully repetitive.

Other answers suggest using `json_encode()`. While that certainly works (if you pass in a boolean value), you will not get the expected output if you pass in something that isn't exactly `true` or `false`. You can, of course, call `json_encode((bool)$yourValue)`, that that will give you what you want, but (in my opinion) it's a little more magical and a little less explicit.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be stuck doing this:

```
is_dir($outputDir) ? 'true' : 'false'
```

Converting a `bool` to a `string` in PHP always converts it to `""` or `"1"`.

Now, this is a bit of a hack, but you can actually just use [`json_encode()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
php > var_dump(json_encode(true));
string(4) "true"
```

Comment: Not quite. `(string)false` will result in the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

This may work,

```
echo json_encode(true);  // string "true"

echo json_encode(false); // string "false"
```

So,

```
 $message .=   "\n\tWhether $testOutputDir is a directory:" . json_encode(!!is_dir($testOutputDir))
                . "\n\tWhether $outputDir is a directory:" . json_encode(is_dir($outputDir))
                . "\n\tWhether $outputDir is readabale:" . json_encode(is_readable($outputDir))
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, And what is the difference between your answer and ternary operator usage?